# SSRS parameters - specifying multiple values in one label

Tags: reporting-services, parameter-passing

Good evening all,

for a parameter in a ssrs report I want to specify the values available. Every label will have the same value, apart from one label - this one will have two values. Everything works fine if I just specify one value per label. But if I use two for one label, it will show error "ORA-01722: invalid number".

I assume I am missing some formatting here to make sure I can pass on two values? The sql query is correct I believe, it specifies the bind by doing "...WHERE account_no in (:account)..."

Below an example of what I am trying to do. Numbers are random

[image: Example]

Would appreciate any help here. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried doing three lines one for the 3333:3333 and one for the 3333:4444

Comment: Yes, I can try that. And then allowing multiple values. Was just wondering whether I can circumvent the allowance for multiple values as I dont want users to be able to select multiple.

Comment: Then you will have to change your query like @Alan suggested in the post below.  Because your current query only does two numbers, not a number and a string, or a number and an array of numbers.

Answer (score 0):

As you used `IN` SSRS will inject the values into your dataset query. If the parameter is text (ignore the fact it's actually numeric), the query will try to process something like `SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE account_no IN ('3333,4444')` which is obviously wrong.

You'll need to parse the values in your dataset query with something like this

```
SELECT * FROM myTable 
WHERE account_no in (SELECT [value] FROM string_split(@account, ','))
```

You haven't mentioned what database you are using, the above is based on SQL Server but the same principle applies.